# SQL query to print the name of the students who are a part of the symmetric pair

Tags: mysql

Given the tables **student**, **mathematics_marks**, **science_marks**

**student**

- student_id (Primary Key) | smallint
- student_name                  | varchar(30)

**mathematics_marks**

- student_id (Primary Key) | smallint
- score                                | float (5,2)

**science_marks**

- student_id (Primary Key) | smallint
- score                                | float (5,2)

A student is called as being a part of a symmetric pair if the marks obtained by that student in science is equal to the marks obtained by some other student in mathematics and the marks obtained in mathematics are the same as marks obtained by the other student in science.

**I am trying to solve the above problem with the following query:**

```sql
SELECT s.student_name 
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN (mathematics_marks m CROSS JOIN science_marks sc) 
    ON (s.student_id = m.student_id AND m.student_id = sc.student_id)
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mathematics_marks m 
                    WHERE sc.score=m.score 
                    AND m.score=sc.score)
    ORDER BY student_name;
```

I am not getting correct output. Can anyone help me out where i am going wrong?

Comment: it seems like poor design to have a separate table for each subject. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In a very simple way

```
select s.student_name 'student_name'
from student s
inner join mathematics_marks m
on m.student_id = s.student_id
inner join science_marks sc 
on sc.student_id = s.student_id
where m.score in ( select score from science_marks ) and 
      sc.score in ( select score from mathematics_marks )
ORDER BY student_name;
```

Comment: Please specify what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT s.student_name
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN mathematics_marks m ON m.student_id = s.student_id
LEFT JOIN science_marks sc ON sc.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE m.score IN (SELECT score FROM science_marks) OR sc.score IN (SELECT score FROM mathematics_marks)
```

Comment: A useful exercise can be to execute `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query]` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS`, and then compare the original query with that as parsed by the SQL engine.

Comment: explain what your thoughts.

Comment: what happens when a student has the same `score` value for mathematics and science? does a student form a symmetric pair with themselves? seems like the query pattern here would return essentially every student that as a score in math that matches any score in science, and a score in science that matches any score in math, without regard to whether those matching scores are from the same student, forming a pair..

Answer (score 0):

Cross Join all students and then compare the marks for each student with other students.

```
select student1.student_name, student2.student_name
from (
         select s1.student_id, s1.student_name, m1.score "m_score", sc1.score "sc_score"
         from student s1
                  join mathematics_marks m1 on s1.student_id = m1.student_id
                  join science_marks sc1 on s1.student_id = sc1.student_id) student1,
     (
         select s2.student_id, s2.student_name, m2.score "m_score", sc2.score "sc_score"
         from student s2
                  join mathematics_marks m2 on s2.student_id = m2.student_id
                  join science_marks sc2 on s2.student_id = sc2.student_id) student2

where student1.student_id<>student2.student_id
  and student1.m_score = student2.sc_score
  and student1.sc_score = student2.m_score;
```

Comment: don't mix the old school comma syntax for the join operation with the newer JOIN keyword syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you need multiple joins of the 2 marks tables and finally to get the names of the students you need to join the table student twice:

```
select st1.student_name, st2.student_name
from mathematics_marks m1
inner join science_marks s1 on s1.student_id > m1.student_id and s1.score = m1.score
inner join mathematics_marks m2 on m2.student_id = s1.student_id 
inner join science_marks s2 on s2.student_id < m2.student_id and s2.score = m2.score
inner join student st1 on st1.student_id = m1.student_id
inner join student st2 on st2.student_id = m2.student_id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hj3NkVPuPvW8hpxEdd4rVa/0).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and get all score under single table let's create a view.

```
create view student_marks as select mm.student_id,mm.score as m_score, sm.score as s_score  
        from mathematics_marks mm
        inner join science_marks sm on mm.student_id=sm.student_id;
```

now we have all marks under single table. 
so we need to do self join of above view and find students who satisfy the symmetric condition

```
select distinct s.* 
from student_marks sm1
inner join student_marks sm2 on sm1.m_score=sm2.s_score and sm2.m_score=sm1.s_score
left join student s on s.student_id = sm1.student_id or s.student_id=sm2.student_id;
```

If you don't want to create view, you can simply replace `student_marks` with the view query.